# Manipulating variables in Processing.js from outside the canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing

I made a certain piece of Processing code that draws a symbol based on parameters set in `setup()`.

I want to make a web page, using Processing.js, that will allow me to change those parameters (all floats) from text boxes in the browser and then redraw.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Sure it's possible, go for it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Please check out [the example](https://jsfiddle.net/rw5rfvx9/) and [read the official documentation](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#mixingjsandprocessing). JSFiddle code:

```
<div id="msg">Your message!</div>
<script>
  var jsString = "Hello from JavaScript!";
  var printMessage = function(msg) {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Message: " + msg;
  };
  var w = 300, h = 200;
</script>
<script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="processing-canvas">
  String processingString = "Hello from Processing!";
  void setup() {
    size(w, h);
    printMessage(jsString + " " + processingString);
  }
</script>
<canvas id="processing-canvas"></canvas>
```